# Observer Pattern for many-to-many relation

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

I have channels and users, users can subscribe to channels. When video is posted on the channel, it notifies users that are subscribed to that channel.

I want to implement it using observer pattern. The problem is that as I understand you have only one subject in observer pattern, so it's one-to-many relation. Now I'm thinking about two approaches, one of them is having multiple subjects (channels) and the other one is having one subject that in notify method takes channel as an argument and it notifies users from there.

So which one is correct or maybe there is another way for doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the system can well be implemented with the Observer pattern and one-to-many relations. Another slightly more complicated pattern you might be interested in is called [Event Aggregator](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html). Both the event emitters and the event listeners register themselves with the event aggregator which coordinates the event passing to the interested parties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't believe it is import to implement any pattern in a correct way. More import is that it solves your problem and stays simple. And pattern give you good ideas to handle certain problems.

To me the second idea:"having one subject that in notify method takes channel as an argument and it notifies users from there." Sound good and much simpler. I don't see any problems there.